# Show Bootstrap carousel indicator as number

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I would like to display the slide number of a bootstrap carousel as text in a HTML page, not using the standard indicators, for example 2 of 6 and have it update as slides change. My implantation of the carousel only displays 1 slide at a time. How do I go about that ?

Comment: I guess each slide when it's 'active'  has a specific class ( className ). Check index of the item with that class in the array of slide items. and display it. ( that's just one possible solution might be others ). If you want a more specific solution please post here your code that reproduces the described situation and also what you have tried to solve your problem. Happy coding !

Comment: Can you please provide the code of your implementation?

Comment: use owl carousel 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/